# ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, linker, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Analytics in my iOS App. However unable to build after adding the Google Analytics sdk (v 3.01) which is the latest version in Xcode 5.

I have included all the dependent libraries/frameworks but still no go.

Below is the Activity Log:

```
 Ld /Users/yashsoni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Draft-MovieApp-dnrjzfyordxcuggjpxwhqsoydvvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RamLeela.app/RamLeela normal armv7
cd /Users/yashsoni/Documents/NetProjects/Draft-MovieApp
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -L/Users/yashsoni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Draft-MovieApp-dnrjzfyordxcuggjpxwhqsoydvvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/yashsoni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Draft-MovieApp-dnrjzfyordxcuggjpxwhqsoydvvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/yashsoni/Documents/NetProjects/Draft-MovieApp -filelist /Users/yashsoni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Draft-MovieApp-dnrjzfyordxcuggjpxwhqsoydvvy/Build/Intermediates/Draft-MovieApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/Ramleela.build/Objects-normal/armv7/RamLeela.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -lGoogleAnalyticsServices -framework CoreData -framework SystemConfiguration -lsqlite3 -framework CFNetwork -framework AdSupport -lz -lsqlite3.0 -framework Twitter -framework CoreLocation -framework Security -framework Accounts -framework Social -framework MessageUI -framework FacebookSDK -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/yashsoni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Draft-MovieApp-dnrjzfyordxcuggjpxwhqsoydvvy/Build/Intermediates/Draft-MovieApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/Ramleela.build/Objects-normal/armv7/RamLeela_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/yashsoni/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Draft-MovieApp-dnrjzfyordxcuggjpxwhqsoydvvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RamLeela.app/RamLeela

ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Hi Yash, I am having the same problem. Curious to know if you have found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use xcode 5.02 or Xcode 5.1 (stable version) and then add google analytic accordingly then hopefully these errors will be resolved.
Same problems I am facing too before installing xcode 5.02.Hopefully it will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your library in "LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS"?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have ans so late,It was a architecture problem. Ther error was only for iPhone 5s 64 bit Architecture. After updating the Google analytics framework got it working..!!

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you update the project settings as recommended by XCode , If its showing, This should solve this kind of issues most of times.